# Set alarms after rebooting Phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, notificationmanager, android-reboot

I have a little question. I set my notifications in specific times using AlarmManager. The times I set notifications for are stored in SQLLite database. They all work perfect except the moment I reboot the phone. alarmManager looses their repeatings of course.

I would like to ask what is the best solution in this situation? I have my alarmManager set in MainActivity and I set my notification inside BroadcastReceiver as you can see in the code below:

Here is how I call it from MainActivity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNT, count);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, count, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), WEEK_LENGTH_MS, pendingIntent);
```

And here is Broadcast Receiver's method onReceive

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        CharSequence message = intent.getStringExtra(DayActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        Intent intentNotification = new Intent(context,DayActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent.getIntExtra(DayActivity.EXTRA_COUNT,0), intentNotification, 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_logo,context.getString(R.string.app_name), System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        nm.notify(intent.getIntExtra(DayActivity.EXTRA_COUNT,0), notif);

    }
```

I am declaring BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED event, but it always calls just empty notification at the time i start the phone and never more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to ask what is the best solution in this situation?

Register a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to call `setRepeating()` on `AlarmManager` to re-establish your schedules.

> I am declaring BroadcastReceiver for BOOT_COMPLETED event, but it always calls just empty notification at the time i start the phone and never more.

The objective of the `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` should be to reschedule your alarms. You might wish to consider using a separate `BroadcastReceiver` than the one you are using for the alarm events themselves.

Comment: So you are saying to use something like OnBootReceiver where I will  get times and using alarmManager call the first BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @JanOmacka: Yes. You are welcome to have one `BroadcastReceiver` handle both roles, but you will need to distinguish between the boot event and the alarm event, such as by examining the action string of the incoming `Intent`. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) uses that approach, as the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast will have a non-`null` action string, while the explicit `Intent` I used in the `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager` will have a `null` action string.